# Difference between locally and globally defined function

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

What is the difference between a function defined locally at $0$ and globally at $0$ on a set $S$? My textbook keeps referring to these things, but I couldn't find any definition about it anywhere. Can someone please elaborate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $S$ has a topology, e.g. is the real line, then being defined locally means being defined on some neighborhood $U$ of zero, and being defined globally just means being defined on the whole set. But "defined globally at zero" is a strange thing to say. If you can post a more exact quote exemplifying your textbook's usage, we can probably answer better.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks for your answer. I am reading Spivak's book Calculus on manifolds. Here is the question I took it from [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445061/whats-the-intuition-with-partitions-of-unity) I am studying partition of unity, see Ted Shifrin's answer please

Answer (score 1):

In the general context of topology, the term “*locally at $x ∈ S$*” most commonly means “for a *local basis* of $x ∈ S$” – This of course begs the question: What is a *[local basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system)*?, which will take you to the even more fundamental questions:

- What is a [*neighbourhood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics))?, and
- What is a [*topological space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space)?

If you don’t know these notions yet, you don’t have to learn them to understand what is meant in the context of defining functions in real analysis:

For $S ⊂ ℝ$, your textbook probably takes a function $f$ to be *defined locally* at $x ∈ S$ if there is a *neighbourhood $V$ of $x$* on which $f$ is defined, – i.e. a set $V ⊂ S$ such that for some $ε > 0$, the $ε$-ball $B_ε(x) = \{y ∈ S;~|y - x| < ε\}$ is contained in $V$.

A function that is *globally defined* on $S$ should just be the same as a function on $S$. The term is probably only used for the contrast to something which is *locally* defined. So “globally defined” means “defined, … and not just locally!”.

See also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1073082/42242), concerning the different concept of *local properties* with which you shouldn’t confuse this, as explained in the answer by Najib.